# See all changes since last commit with Sublimerge and Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublime-text-3

Im running Sublime Text 3 and Ive installed Sublimerge. How can I see a diff of all files that have changed since my last commit?

I need the same functionality that i have in PHP storm where I have this panel:

[image]

And when I view the diff I have this view:

[image]

This icon allows me to see the next file with changes:

[image]

Can you do a similar thing with Sublime Text 3?

With [ctrl]+[alt]+[d] I can open Sublimerge's diff options. The closest to what I need is "Show uncommitted changes.." or "Show unpushed changes.." however I have to do this for each file individually. This isnt practice for me, for instance if im doing a find and replace on SASS files there may be 10s or even 100s of files that have been changed.